# What is the best tool to make big screen size of document? high resolution document?

Tags: software-recommendation, resolution, document-setup

I'd like to make huge scale of document. for example multi depth of mind-map, software full stack diagram, and flow of full logic.

I have tried using Powerpoint, Excel, One-note, Prezi,...
There are some limitations and cons for each program like as followings

1. pre-fixed resolution should be defined
2. browsing and magnifying specific area, and editing something, it is very slow 
   or flickering, and therefore presenting is also not good enough.
3. adding another big page, it is difficult to go page prev/next or move up/down. tools are not easy to handle these functionalists.

Therefore, I'd like to get advice from here, the frontiers

Comment: please recommend tags for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly sorry to reply as an answer, commenting needed reputation.
I would suggest you to try vectors or [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) and if you are looking for applications to use, try Illustrator or inkscape.

Comment: It is similar to Gliffy made by Atlassian, but fast and easy to connect each objects. good! I will try more!